# attach functions to pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This may be a very basic question (and I can remove it if there are objections to it).

Suppose I have a function that I reuse multiple times in various projects:

```
def sort_clean(x, sort_cols):
   x.sort(sort_cols, inplace=True)
   x.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

I want to make this a part of `pandas` module such that whenever I do `import pandas` and define a dataframe `myDf` I can get `mfDf.sort_clean` as an available function for that dataframe. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass a DataFrame

```
class NewDataFrame(pandas.DataFrame):
    def sort_clean(self, sort_cols):
        self.sort(sort_cols, inplace=True)
        self.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

For example:

```
In [25]: class NewDataFrame(pandas.DataFrame):
   ....:     def sort_clean(self, sort_cols):
   ....:         self.sort(sort_cols, inplace=True)
   ....:         self.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
   ....:         

In [26]: dfrm
Out[26]: 
          A         B         C
0  0.382531  0.287066  0.345749
1  0.725201  0.450656  0.336720
2  0.146883  0.266518  0.011339
3  0.111154  0.190367  0.275750
4  0.757144  0.283361  0.736129
5  0.039405  0.643290  0.383777
6  0.632230  0.434664  0.094089
7  0.658512  0.368150  0.433340
8  0.062180  0.523572  0.505400
9  0.287539  0.899436  0.194938

[10 rows x 3 columns]

In [27]: my_df = NewDataFrame(dfrm) 

In [28]: my_df.sort_clean(["B", "C"])

In [29]: my_df
Out[29]: 
          A         B         C
0  0.111154  0.190367  0.275750
1  0.146883  0.266518  0.011339
2  0.757144  0.283361  0.736129
3  0.382531  0.287066  0.345749
4  0.658512  0.368150  0.433340
5  0.632230  0.434664  0.094089
6  0.725201  0.450656  0.336720
7  0.062180  0.523572  0.505400
8  0.039405  0.643290  0.383777
9  0.287539  0.899436  0.194938

[10 rows x 3 columns]
```

But be aware that using any functions which return new `DataFrame` objects will not return a `NewDataFrame` automatically.

Normal monkey-patching (e.g. just creating a new attribute onto an existing `DataFrame` instance like `df.sort_clean = sort_clean`) will be tricky because the method needs the instance value supplied as the implicit first argument, especially since you do in-place mutation. For that you'd constantly have to use `functools.partial`, or a `lambda` with a default, to achieve the same thing:

```
df.sort_clean = lambda sort_cols, x=df: sort_clean(x, sort_cols)
```

Note that with the `lambda` approach you need to specify the argument that will have a default last (arguments with default values must follow arguments without default values in Python). You can get around this if you choose to use `functools.partial` instead.

```
import functools
df.sort_clean = functools.partial(sort_clean, df)
```

Comment: thanks. I didn't know the term was called "monkey-patching". I just googled it and found a link on the pandas documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/faq.html#adding-features-to-your-pandas-installation

Comment: Monkey-patching is really not a good way to solve these kinds of problems. If it works for you, then by all means use it, but it's a very unsafe technique that often leads to littering the code with all kinds of extra code to check if the monkey patch was correctly applied, and to re-apply it if not.

Comment: I know, but I'm some scripts so often, that it might just reduce my efforts

Comment: Although I agree monkey-patching is generally to be avoided, I don't see why it's tricky.  `pd.DataFrame.sort_clean = sort_clean` will Just Work(tm).

Comment: @Mr.F: I don't understand your concerns about "default value for the x argument".  After adding the function to DataFrame itself, self is passed as the first argument (which the function calls "x", which doesn't matter) and it behaves as it should.  Try it yourself, as that'll probably be more convincing than anything I can say.

Comment: @DSM, what if I don't want to pass self as the first argument. For example, suppose I have a file format .xyz and I have two functions `to_xyz(self, path)` and `read_xyz(path)` - and I want them to behave similar to `to_csv` and `read_csv` ?